# Pass parameter to UserControl in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm using Syncfusion's `DockingManager` with the [Adapter for MVVM](http://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/MVVM-Adapter-for-WPF-Docking-Manager.aspx) so a List of ViewModels which implement `IDockElement` can be bound.

I'm using it this way:

```
<dm:DockingAdapter Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding DockingItems}" />
```

In addition I'm using the latest version of Catel and its [Custom controls](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Using+a+custom+control).

The MVVM Adapter of the `DockingManager` needs these entries, to create a view from a ViewModel:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:EventEditorViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <events:EventEditorControl/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The problem is, that my `EventEditorControl` has a parameter in its constructor which needs the ViewModel.

How do I pass the correct ViewModel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass parameters to constructors using xaml.

Make you parameter a dependency property:

```
<events:EventEditorControl MyParameterAsDependencyProperty="{Binding SomeProperty}"  />
```